# Automator sequential file rename with variable padding

Tags: automator, macos

I want to rename selected files in the finder sequentially. To do this I have created an Automator workflow.

In the Automator workflow you can specify how many digits long you want the rename to be I.e. 3 = 001, 002 etc...

I would like this number to be inferred from the number of files selected.

Is this possible?

Thanks for any help!

Ben

Comment: As far as I know, you can't do this with Automator's drag & drop components, but you could do it with an AppleScript.

Comment: Ben, would a shell script (callable from Terminal or Automator) be a valid alternative for you?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Either an AppleScript or shell script would work great - I'll get on this at some point and post it. I just wanted to know whether I was missing something like a variable that I could use in the automator UI. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with Automator. You can only specify the number of digits manually.